# Consecutive Sequences to Process Macro Inside a Macro

Tags: expl3, xparse, seq

I have a macro which uses inner macros to process pairs of arguments. The essential part can be broken down to

`\mymacro{\inside{A}{1};\inside{B}{2},\inside{C}{3}}`.

Originally I had all pairs processed and then printed, separated by commas, using a sequence to get an output like "1A, 2B, 3C", "1A, 2B" or "1A", for three, two and one arguments, respectively.

Now the requirements have changed and I need the output to be: "1,A 2,B 3.C", "1,A 2.B" or "1.A".

I figured, this could be done with sequences and came up with this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3} % expl3 loaded explicitly - not necessary because it is already loaded by xparse
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__map_current_tl
\tl_new:N \l__map_tl
\tl_new:N \l__inside_tl

\seq_new:N \l__my_seq
\seq_new:N \l__second_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \mymacro {>{\SplitList{;}} m}
{
    \mymacro_process_func:n {#1}
    \mymacro_output_func:n
    \\
}

\NewDocumentCommand \inside {m m}
{
    \inside_process_func:nn {#1} {#2}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \inside_process_func:nn #1 #2
{
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__inside_tl
    { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__inside_tl {#2 !! #1} }
    { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__inside_tl {~ #2 !! #1} }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymacro_process_func:n #1
{
    % make sure token lists and sequences are empty
    \tl_clear:N \l__map_current_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l__map_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l__inside_tl

    \seq_clear:N \l__my_seq
    \seq_clear:N \l__second_seq

    \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \mymacro_map_func:n
    \tl_show:N {\l__map_tl}
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__my_seq {;} \l__map_tl
%   \seq_show:N \l__my_seq
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__my_seq {} {} {}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymacro_map_func:n #1
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l__map_current_tl {#1}
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__map_tl
    { \tl_set_eq:NN \l__map_tl \l__map_current_tl }
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__map_tl {;}
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__map_tl \l__map_current_tl
    }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__map_current_tl {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymacro_output_func:n 
{
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__second_seq {!!} \l__inside_tl
%   \seq_show:N \l__second_seq
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__second_seq {.} {,} {.}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Achieved:\\
\mymacro{\inside{A}{1}}
\mymacro{\inside{A}{1};\inside{B}{2}}
\mymacro{\inside{A}{1};\inside{B}{2};\inside{C}{3}}

Desired:\\
1.A \\ 1,A 2.B \\ 1,A 2,B 3.C

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the code does what it should:

[image: Sequences Output]

However, I fear it is not very efficient and it looks very dubious to me. For example, I used `\l__my_seq` in `\mymacro_process_func:n` with spaces in a previous version:

```
\seq_set_split:NnV \l__my_seq {;} \l__map_tl
\seq_use:Nnnn \l__my_seq {~} {~} {~}
```

but the spaces did not appear in the output. (In fact, replacing all `~` by `?` prints none, one or two question marks before the output, respectively.)

- Is there a better (shorter) way to *without the need to change the use of `\mymacro` and `\inside`?* (I can't change all the macros in my document)
- Is there, in general, a better approach to this problem?

By the way: I am not sure if my solution (naming, etc.) complies with all rules and conventions, so any comment on this is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement it seems you don't need to loop over the input you can simply execute the list, typesetting each item as you go.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mymacro#1{#1\relax}
\def\inside#1#2#3{\ifx\relax#3#2.#1\else#2,#1 \fi}

\begin{document}


Achieved:\\
\mymacro{\inside{A}{1}}\\
\mymacro{\inside{A}{1};\inside{B}{2}}\\
\mymacro{\inside{A}{1};\inside{B}{2};\inside{C}{3}}

Desired:\\
1.A \\ 1,A 2.B \\ 1,A 2,B 3.C


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is much shorter. Will it also work if I had to further process the numbers? I did not mention it in the minimal example to keep it minimal but some of the numbers could be ranges which I inserted using a SplitList in the `\inside` macro as well, using this in an `\SIrange`.

Comment: @Echo if the processing of each `\inside` is independent of others then the same basic technique  will work, even if you code the more complicated `\inside` logic using expl3

Comment: Due to my lack of experience I don't see how, but I will take a closer look. I will accept your answer - as it does all I asked for. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.